# Data types for WiFi-information

Tags: mysql, sql

I´m going to create a database to store information about different wireless networks for a small project I´m about to start. (Wardriving to see how many networks in can find in my city). I am new to databases and i would like to have some guidance and counseling from you guys about which data types to use when creating the tables that will hold my data.

The values I´m interested in storing is the following:

id - An growing number starting from 1 and going up as i add data
ssid - The name of the network
mac - the accesspoints mac-address
channel - the channel the ap is using
encryption - wep, wpa, wpa2 and so on
longitude - gps position where i found the ap
latitude - gps position where i found the ap
first seen - date and time when i scanned and logged the information the first time
last seen - If i scan the same network a second time i would like to get the "last seen" time and date

What i have so far is:

```
id INT(7)
ssid VARCHAR(32)
mac VARCHAR(17)
channel INT(2)
encryption VARCHAR(255)
longitude VARCHAR(255)
latitude VARCHAR(255)
first seen DATETIME
last seen DATETIME
```

Is this OK or should i change something?

Example data that i collect.

SSID: B2_private_E3
MAC: 00:01:38:73:68:3C
Channel: 11
Privacy: WPA
Ciper: TKIP
Auth: PSK
Latitude: 60.012444
Longitude: 15.792303
First seen: Thu Jun  6 15:13:15 2013
Last seen: Thu Jun  6 15:14:26 2013

Comment: What are the standards for WIFI? You should be able to extract the allowed data types and lengths from it.

Comment: be carefull with privacy regulations.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - Yes i started looking at that and found out that for example SSID can only be maximum 32 characters, so thats good to know. Need to look at the other values too.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on you, not on some random guys on the Internet. But, peeking over at your code, I can say that it is enough for a Wi-Fi network.

Comment: I know it´s up to me but I´m just wondering if there is some "best practise" about which data types to use for different information. I started reading about data types but it´s confusing ;D

Comment: Well, your table looks fine to me. I think it's gonna be a nice project.